Android app starts Google Maps with Satellite view
You can start in your app the Google Maps app with code like:
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);

Starting in Streetview mode is possible as well.
Is it possible to start Google Maps immediately with the Satellite view?
I could not find information about it via e.g. this Google Maps intent information.

You can try a different form of the intent using a universal, cross-platform URL to launch described here.
This form permits the use of a basemap parameter with a value of satellite.
The parameters of interest are here.
Code fragment.  Launch map intent on button press (labeled "Launch Map")  - ignore other bits in the display:
Button b = findViewById(R.id.main_button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Paris coordinates
            double latitude = 48.8575;
            double longitude = 2.3514;
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=%f,%f&zoom=10&basemap=satellite", latitude, longitude);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

And result:

